# VBA code to hide/unhide charts/boxes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I wrote a vba code to hide/unhide charts/list boxes in my active sheet that I assigned to a "button" or just a shape that I pulled from the Insert Tab in excel. This code works with 1 shape, but I can't get it to work with multiple. I'm new to VBA so I'm not sure about all the nuances with the syntax. Here's what I have:

```
Sub OverviewB()

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters

        If .Text = "Hide Overview" Then

            .Text = "Show Overview"

            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 20", "List Box 1", "Chart 19", "List Box 3", "Chart 22", "List Box 4", "Chart 24", "List Box 5").Visible = False

        Else

            .Text = "Hide Overview"

                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 20", "List Box 1", "Chart 19", "List Box 3", "Chart 22", "List Box 4", "Chart 24", "List Box 5").Visible = True



        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I did have a line seperator "_" in the middle of my chart/list box names so that it wasn't as wide, but I took that out because I thought it might be causing some errors.

Can anyone see where the syntax error is here? The error I receive is:
**"Runtime Error 450": Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assingment.**

Comment: It's been ages since I've done any Excel programming but I think you need Shapes.Range( ... ). ActiveSheet.Shapes just gives you a collection and you need to create a Range object from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message gives you some hints, *Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assingment.* You're sending too many arguments to the `.Shapes` property.

The [`Worksheet.Shapes` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821817.aspx) collection takes a single argument and returns a [`Shapes` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841148.aspx), which is a collection of [`Shape` objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835842.aspx). From the dox,

> Use `Shapes(index)`, where `index` is the shape’s name or index number, to return a single Shape object.

And further:

> Use `Shapes.Range(index)`, where `index` is the shape’s name or index number or an array of shape names or index numbers, to return a `ShapeRange` collection that represents a subset of the Shapes collection.

You need to set the elements in an array and specify the items within range

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart 20", "List Box 1", "Chart 19", "List Box 3", "Chart 22", "List Box 4", "Chart 24", "List Box 5")).Visible = True
```

Comment: How can I dim this shape when it is clicked and return it to normal color upon a second click

Comment: Thanks David, I will go deeper next time as stated :) @DukeLuke I am not quite sure if the life cycle of the object considers click event, you would need to look deeper for that matter HINT: Google Handle click events on Shapes.